# Why do my arrows bounce off of other players?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Whenever I am playing multiplayer and I shoot an arrow at someone it reflects off. Even when they don't have any armor on, it still reflects. Is this a glitch? It is survival mode.

Comment: sounds like what happens when you shoot someone who is in creative mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are in Creative mode. Changing to Survival will hurt the player and the arrows will not bounce.

Comment: But  it is survival

Answer (score 1):

I realized that it was because I can't hit other players in pocketmine, only in regular servers.

Answer (score 0):

If the world is on peaceful arrows won't hit other people and will bounce off

Comment: ? Idon't think this is accurate at least now?

Answer (score -2):

You just need to change the difficulty on and the arrows won't bounce now